# JQuery when().done() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need run some animation chain. I tried to use following code, but always second() was run at the same time as first()

example one:

```
var first = function(){
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    $('#ajax-contract-info').fadeOut(1400, function() {
                    $('#ajax-contract-info').removeClass('in');
                    $('#ajax-contract-info').css('display', '');
                    d.resolve();
            });
    return d.promise();
};

var second = function() {
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    $('#ajax-other-fields').fadeIn(1400, function() { d.resolve() });
    return d.promise();
};

$.when(first())
.done(second());
```

example two:

```
var first = function(){
    return $('#ajax-contract-info').fadeOut(1400, function() {
                    $('#ajax-contract-info').removeClass('in');
                    $('#ajax-contract-info').css('display', '');
            }).promise();
};

var second = function() {
    return $('#ajax-other-fields').fadeIn(1400, function() { d.resolve() }).promise();
};

$.when(first())
.done(second());
```

Where is a mistake?

P.S. I know, that I can use "complete" setting inside animation call, but I have a lot off animation with big condition list, using of "complete" setting will make code unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.done(second())` **calls** `second` and passes its return value into `done`, just like `foo(bar())` calls `bar` and passes its result into `foo`. You just want to pass the function reference, so leave off the `()`:

```
$.when(first())
.done(second);
// No () ---^
```

You can also just use `then` on `first()`, no need for `$.when` unless you're combining parallel promises:

```
first().then(second);
```

And if you had a third, you could chain that onto the end, and it will wait for `second` to finish since `second` returns a promise:

```
first().then(second).then(third);
```